# Custom exception handlers never called in ServiceStack 4

Tags: servicestack

In ServiceStack 3 I had a custom handler decorating the result DTO in case of exceptions:

```
ServiceExceptionHandler = (request, exception) =>
{
    var ret = DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, exception);
    var error = ret as HttpError;

    if ( error == null )
        return ret;

    // ...
    error.Response = new MyErrorResponse
    {
        ResponseStatus = responseStatus,
        // ...
    };

    return ret;
};
```

After migrating to ServiceStack 4 I tried different hooks:

1. ServiceExceptionHandlers.Add
2. OnExceptionTypeFilter
3. Own ServiceRunner with overridden HandleException

Neither of them is been called when exceptions occur. What am I missing?
I'm using the new Task based services, if this is relevant.

**Edit:** A simple test service included in my solution triggers the hooks:

```
[Route("/test")]
public class TestRequest : IReturn<int>
{
}

public class TestService : Service
{
    public Task<int> Get(TestRequest request)
    {
        throw new Exception("Ha!");
    }
}
```

**Edit2:** Seems to be a bug in the handling of asynchronous services. If I move the exception from the synchronous to the asynchronous part of the handler, none of the hooks are called:

```
public class TestService : Service
{
    public async Task<int> Get(TestRequest request)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        throw new Exception("Ha!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been fixed in ServiceStack.